# P5 vertices add strokeWeight

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In my code different vertices will align (routes on a map). I want to visualize if more people take the same route -> I want to generate bigger Strokes.
Is there a possibility to "add" stroke weights?

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,600);
}

function draw() {
    strokeWeight(2);
    beginShape();          
    vertex(0,0);
    vertex(500,60);           
    endShape(); 

    noFill();
    strokeWeight(2);
    beginShape();          
    vertex(0,0);
    vertex(500,60); 
    vertex(400,400);
    endShape();  
}
```

Here are 2 overlaying vertices with `strokweight(2);`
I want the overlapping part to have a bigger stroke.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do? Just use two hard-coded lines instead of your full program.

Comment: Of course. I edited my question above.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but that's not really a [mcve]. Generally a MCVE should be enough code that we can copy and paste it to run ourselves, but should not include any extra stuff like the reading of the data. Just use hard-coded values to show two lines, and show how you're trying to add the stroke weights to those lines.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? (or is that just a mis-tag?)

Comment: I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways I can think of you might try to do this.

The first is to use transparency in the stroke colours. It doesn't make your strokeWeight thicker but it will make the overlapping routes standout. I've put some code below that you can copy/paste into [Processing](http://processing.org) to try it out. I increased the strokeWeight to 4 to make it easier to see as well.

The second approach is to look at each route being travelled as a series of lines or connections as opposed to a continuous line. 
For each connection between points, count up how many times it is travelled by the different routes and determine your strokeWeight from that.

Eg. Three routes between cities A, B, C, D.

- Route 1: A - B, B - C, C - D
- Route 2: A - D, D - C
- Route 3: C - B, B - D, D - C

Travel count per city connection.

- A - B = 1
- B - C = 2
- C - D = 3
- A - D = 1
- B - D = 2

The first way is quick and easy, the second way is more involved but a lot more flexible.

```
// Quick and easy approach using transparency
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(0, 75); // black with alpha set to 75
  strokeWeight(4);
  beginShape();          
  vertex(0, 0);
  vertex(500, 60);           
  endShape(); 

  noFill();
  strokeWeight(4);
  beginShape();          
  vertex(0, 0);
  vertex(500, 60); 
  vertex(400, 400);
  endShape();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first version is nice, simple and does the Job for now. The second version sounds very interesting to me - but I'm a 'coding-beignner'. I'm not sure how to convert your idea into code. Do you know a tutorial or a code example that does something similar?